# flush(), od_flush() works! or not?

Tags: php, flush

I have this code running in a Windows enviroment with Apache2 and PHP5:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("output_buffering", 0);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);

if (!ob_get_level()) {
    ob_start();
} else {
   ob_end_clean();
   ob_start();
}

for($x=0;$x<10;$x++){
    echo "<br/> Linea .... ".$x;
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(2);

}

?>
```

It's works perfect,

Linea 0 (2 seconds)

Linea 1 (2 seconds)

Linea 2 (2 seconds)

...

Linea 9 (2 seconds)

if I run in a Linux with apache2 and PHP7, don't works,

Linea 0

Linea 1

...

Linea 9 (20 seconds)

but I run script ...

```
php /var/www/line.php
```

It's works well.

I dont undestand difference? Or what must I change in my configuration?

Comment: I probed all scripts in php manual and dont works

Answer (score 0):

9 is your last line so obviously it will take 20 seconds.
it waits for action or browser to response until it reaches the time limit in php.ini file which in you case is set to 20 seconds.
This gives the browser time to respond and i would not play with that setting because if you make it low anyone with slow connection will loose the connection

Comment: Itsn't correct, If I use time_limit(0) occurs the same, it's a problem with other thing

Comment: change 10 to15 in your loop and see if it still happens at 9 it will happen at 14 then because it wait for response or action

Comment: Finish script in Line 15...,in linux enviroment dont woks